# How to resize window in full screen mode

Tags: android

I am using the following attributes for an activity and expect a 
window to resize automatically to occupy space available above IME: 
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" 
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" 
so please tell me how to resize the window when keyboard open in full screen mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Suggest you to try this code in your Activity..

```
Context myContext=YourActivityName;

((Activity) myContext).getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    ((Activity) myContext).requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Comment: hey Zala but problem not solved. layout doesnot resize by applying this code so please help me

Comment: use of this code layout display in fullscreen.what you want accualy?

Comment: please read my question carefully i have one activity whcih is shown in full screen mode but i want that when user touch edit box then screen resize automatically

Comment: Dear share me this link! else how to find this?

Comment: Sorry Dear I am busy i check this code and say what the problem in lunch time please wait Sorry Brother